# add event for listener but not builder in flutter bloc

Tags: flutter, flutter-bloc

Using flutter bloc when I tab on tabs I want to show a dialog. I do this by adding an event to the bloc when the tabs are tapped. In the BlocConsumer the listener listens and show the dialog as expected. However since I added an event to the bloc, the BlocBuilder rebuilds which is expected behaviour(but unwanted) because an event is added. How can I prevent this rebuild? I can add code if needed....

Comment: Have you tried supplying condition on buildWhen?

Answer (score 0):

Use buildWhen and check if the current state is your tab state and return false this will prevent the bloc from the building.

```
BlocConsumer<BlocA, BlocAState>(
  .......

  buildWhen: (previous, current) {
    if(current is YourTabState) {
        return false;
     } 
    return true;
  },

  ......
)
```